# Oracle to SQL Server Date Conversion: Error invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Need to convert date format from (source oracle) yyyy/mm/dd to (target - SQL Server) mm/dd/yyyy.

Current Query:

```
SELECT* FROM WVT.WVCAS 
WHERE to_date(dttmcutpull, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Getting error:

`ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

Please help.

Comment: If it's already a date field you don't have to use to_date, you would just use to_char(dttmcutpull,'mm/dd/yyyy'). Also, you have to set it to equal something, or you will always get that error. If that is a date in the WVT.WVCAS table, and you just want to see the format change, it needs to go after the select.

Answer (score 1):

"Invalid relational operator" usually means that you have a `where` clause without a comparison.  In your case, the `where` clause has the conversion `to_date()`, but no comparison.  Perhaps you mean something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM WVT.WVCAS 
WHERE dttmcutpull > sysdate - 1;
```

In other words, merely converting the data is not sufficient, you have to compare it to something.

If you just want to do the conversion, then put that in the `select`:

```
SELECT w.*,
       to_char(dttmcutpull, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NewDate
FROM WVT.WVCAS w;
```

EDIT:

You have to convert each column independently, not all at once.  `to_char()` takes two arguments, a date and a format:

```
SELECT w.*,
       to_char(dttmcutpull, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date1,
       to_char(DTTMPULLll, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date2,
       to_char(DTTMRUNll, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date3,
       to_char(SYSLOCKDATEll, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date4,
       to_char(SYSMODATEll, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as date5,
       to_char(SYSCREATEDATE 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NewDate
FROM WVT.WVCAS w;
```

Comment: Receiving error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when I run: SELECT w.*,
       to_date(dttmcutpull, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NewDate
FROM WVT.WVCAS w;

Comment: @user3750517 - if it's for display then you should be using `to_char()` as Bob said; and you shouldn't have two format masks for either function.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff now I'm getting a missing right parenthesis error.

Comment: I used this query: SELECT w.*,
       to_char(dttmcutpull, DTTMPULL, DTTMRUN, SYSLOCKDATE, SYSMODATE, SYSCREATEDATE 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NewDate
FROM WVT.WVCAS w;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT w.*,
       TO_CHAR(to_date(dttmcutpull, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NewDate
FROM WVT.WVCAS w;
```

What I am doing is,

- dttmcutpull is a STRING (`VARCHAR`) with format `yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss`
- Initially converting the string to a DATE using `TO_DATE`
- Re-converting the DATE to a string of `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss` using `TO_CHAR` function

Used Syntax is similar to

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR 
( 
    TO_DATE (STRING_FIELD_VALUE, EXISTING_FORMAT_OF_STRING_FIELD_VALUE),
    EXPECTED_FORMAT_OF_NEW_VALUE
) AS NEW_STRING_FIELD_VALUE;
```

**EDIT:** Your Query should be:

1. If dttmcutpull, DTTMPULLll,DTTMRUNll etc are **DATE** datatypes then

   `SELECT w.*,
          to_char(dttmcutpull, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE1,
          to_char(DTTMPULLll, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE2,
          to_char(DTTMRUNll, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE3,
          to_char(SYSLOCKDATEll, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE4,
          to_char(SYSMODATEll, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE5,
          to_char(SYSCREATEDATE 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE6
   FROM WVT.WVCAS w;`
2. If dttmcutpull, DTTMPULLll,DTTMRUNll etc are **VARCHAR**(STRING/CHARACTER) datatypes then

   `SELECT w.*,
          TO_CHAR(to_date(dttmcutpull, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE1,
          TO_CHAR(to_date(DTTMPULLll, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE2,
          TO_CHAR(to_date(DTTMRUNll, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE3,
          TO_CHAR(to_date(SYSLOCKDATEll, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE4,
          TO_CHAR(to_date(SYSMODATEll, 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE5,
          TO_CHAR(to_date(SYSCREATEDATE , 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as NEW_DATE6
   FROM WVT.WVCAS w;`

Comment: Hi Nishanthi....I'm getting this error. Message Code: RR_4035
Message: SQL Error [
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis